# How to add delete button after new row opened using Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to add a delete (minus) button after adding a new row using plus button. I am providing my code below.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >                                             
 <thead>
<tr>
<th>Day</th>
 <th>Category</th>
<th>Sub Subcategory</th>
 <th>Comments Or special promotion</th>
<th>Add More</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr ng-repeat="d in days">
 <td>{{d.day_name}}</td>
 <td>
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
 <tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
 <td>
 <select class="form-control" id="answer_{{$index}}_category" name="answer_{{$index}}_category" ng-model="answer.catagory" ng-options="cat.name for cat in listOfCatagory track by cat.value">
<option value="">Select Category</option>
 </select>
 </td>

 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </td>
 <td>
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
 <tbody>
 <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
 <td>
<select class="form-control" id="answer_{{$index}}_subcategory" name="answer_{{$index}}_subcategory" ng-model="answer.subcatagory" ng-options="sub.name for sub in listOfSubCatagory[$parent.$index] track by sub.value">
<option value="">Select Subcategory</option>
</select>
    </td>

    </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </td>
     <td>
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
     <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="answer in d.answers">
    <td>
     <input type="text" id="answer_{{$index}}_comment" name="answer_{{$index}}_comment" placeholder="Add Comment" ng-model="answers.comment" class="form-control oditek-form">
     </td>

    </tr>
    </tbody>
     </table>
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="submit" name="plus" id="plus" value="+" style="width:20px; text-align:center;" ng-click="addNewRow(d.answers)">
     </td>


     </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

controller file is given below.

```
$scope.days=[];
    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/customerInfo.php?action=day",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        //console.log('day',response.data);
        angular.forEach(response.data,function(obj){
              obj.answers = [];
              $scope.addNewRow(obj.answers);
              $scope.days.push(obj);
        })
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    })
    $scope.addNewRow = function(answers) {
    answers.push({
      category: null,
      subcategory: null,
      comment: null
    });
  };
```

Here I have one `plus` button when user is clicking on it a new row is adding. I need when a new row will add one delete (`minus`) button will create for previous one and `plus` button will remain with new one. When user will click on minus button the corresponding row will be deleted.

Comment: It would be alot easier to help you if you could provide a jsFiddle or a codepen with an example

Comment: @aup: please check this[https://plnkr.co/edit/JiieQZ?p=preview] link.

Comment: Something like this maybe? https://plnkr.co/edit/wM78uPvn2hLIJlNfStQM?p=preview

Comment: please check this after clicked not deleting anything and `-` button should stay with previous row and its throwing this `angular.js:12722 ReferenceError: row is not defined` error.

Comment: Ooops, sorry! Try again please :)

Comment: yes,will it be possible delete button will display with previous row.?

Comment: Not if you intend to remove exactly that row when clicking the deletebutton. It wouldn't make any sense having a delete button next to a row which wont be deleted when pressing it.

Comment: yes,i need to delete button in previous row but not with the created row.

Comment: How will you know what row to delete when you click the delete button?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106588/discussion-between-satya-and-aup).

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML file:

`<button ng-click="removeRow($index)">`

In your angular controller code:

`$scope.removeRow = function(id) {
  angular.forEach(answers, function(currentAnswer, index) {
    if (currentAnswer.id === id) {
      answers.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
}`

Note that `answers` needs to be accessible for this to work.

Comment: its throwing error `angularjs.js:107 ReferenceError: answers is not defined`

Comment: @satya Thats because `answers` is inaccessible. You will need to modify the code myself and others have added in order for it to work. Don't expect us to provide answers you can directly copy paste into your code!

Comment: @Satya u can use $scope.d.answers instead of answers.

Answer (score 0):

add html for remove button beside plus button like below:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="removeNewRow($index)" ng-show="$first && !$last">
```

and add a function in controller:

```
$scope.removeNewRow= function(index) {
       $scope.d.answers.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: ok,but it is showing the remove button from the begining which i dont need and after clicking on remove button this error `angularjs.js:107 TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined` is coming.Here i need when new row will create the remove button will display with previous one.

Comment: I have updated. you can try now. I need to add $scope.d.answers instead of $scope.answers.